# Block specific page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ip-restrictions

Is there a way to restrict access to certain IP address for a specific page in WordPress? Can't find any resource online for this issue.

Say my site is example.com and I have a page example.com/free/ which only certain IP address can access. Other pages should be available to public.

Comment: This really depends on who is hosting your wordpress site, also the questions it very broad and not very fitted for stackoverflow.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/

Comment: As per plugin's author: the plugin is geared toward restricting entire sites rather than specific pages.

Comment: Do you prefer going with code?

Comment: you can create a "restrict by IP" template, and use this in the top `if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != 'theIpAddressHere') {wp_redirect(get_home_url())}` or something similar

Comment: Then everything that needs to be blocked by ip, just needs that template.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Wordpress(MU) must-use plugin.

in the plugin :

```
$request_uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
if ($request_uri === '/free') {
  if(ip_address_allowed){
  }
  else{
    //redirect to where -ever
  }
}
```